# React Uncaught TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I've checked on stackoverflow for this error and the only results i've been getting is that the functions needs to be binded with this.
but i have done so in my code and the error still persists.
I cant figure out why this is happening. 
full code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MrHasuu/pen/KvVMjV?editors=0010) and a shorted copy below

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setOperand = this.setOperand.bind(this);
    this.calculate = this.calculate.bind(this);
    this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      currentValue: 0,
      secondValue: 0,
      operand: null,
      isNewNum: false
    };
  }

  setOperand = (value) => {
    //set data from input
  };

  calculate = () => {
    //math stuff
    this.setState = ({
      currentValue: result,
      isNewNum: false
    });
  };

  updateValue = (value) => {
    if(!this.state.isNewNum){ //first Number
      var newNum = "";
      //set values
      this.setState({
        currentValue: newNum
      });
    } else {
      var newNum2 = "";
      //set values
      this.setState({
        secondValue: newNum2
      });
    }
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <div id="main">
        <p>isNewNum = {`${this.state.isNewNum}`}</p>

        {this.state.isNewNum ?  <Display display ={this.state.secondValue}/> : <Display display ={this.state.currentValue}/>}
        <div>
          <Buttons value={1} onClick={this.updateValue}/>
          ...
          <Buttons value={'+'} onClick={this.setOperand}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  };
}


ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

er.

you actually create a local copy of the `setState` property of your instance in the calculate method, severing the proto chain to `React.Component` as it starts being resolved locally.

this is the error:

```
this.setState = ({
  currentValue: result,
  isNewNum: false
});
```

that extra = is an assignment. any subsequent calls that do `setState` would fail

Comment: That's the whole point. Prototype chain finds an ownProperty `setState` and it's no longer a function

Comment: so in other words i accidentally assigned setState and that's what was causing the problem. and all calls to it wont work no more cause its no longer a function. thank you so much!

Comment: a case may be made that it needs to be configured as `writable: false` in the react code for the property descriptor of a class that inherits from `React.Component` - but this would be bad for people who are debugging setState issues etc and want to overload it.

Comment: @Kinduser https://codepen.io/MrHasuu/pen/KvVMjV?editors=0010 i commented it on my codepen, and updated code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rebind the callbacks in the constructor as arrow function inherit the context of the enclosing class (in this case the component).

Comment: That's not the case, unfortunately.

Comment: i rebinded them because i thought that would solve the issue, but it doesn't work bind or unbind. does anyone know why this is happening? i'm just trying to practice and learn React